# Converting java 8 lambda expression to operation on list in java 7

Tags: java, lambda

I trying to convert this section of code to get rid of the lambda expressions so it'll be able to work in java 7

```
pausedTriggerGroups.stream().
            forEach((group) -> {
              pausedTriggerGroups.remove(group);
        });
```

And my code in java7 was as follows

```
pausedTriggerGroups.removeAll(pausedTriggerGroups);
```

and this:

```
triggersByKey.values(new TriggerByJobPredicate(jobKey))
            .stream()
            .map(v -> (OperableTrigger) v.getTrigger())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to this:

```
List<OperableTrigger> result= new ArrayList<>();
    for (TriggerWrapper value : triggersByKey.values()) {
        result.add(value.getTrigger());
    }
```

and this:

```
triggersByKey.values().stream().
            filter((trigger) -> (trigger.jobKey.equals(jobKey))).
            forEach((trigger) -> {
              trigList.add(trigger);
            });
```

to this:

```
for (TriggerWrapper triggerWrapper : triggersByKey.values()) {
        if(triggerWrapper.getTrigger().getJobKey().equals(jobKey)){
            trigList.add(triggerWrapper);
        }
    }
```

the conversions are good or have some error?

Comment: `pausedTriggerGroups.removeAll(pausedTriggerGroups);` is just `pausedTriggerGroups.clear()` really.

Comment: Nomenclature note: a stream pipeline is not a lambda expression. It just typically makes use of lambda expressions.

Comment: thanks, but the conversions is good?

Comment: About your very first code block: Altering a Collection while a stream based on it is still active is probably going to cause you problems.

Comment: Your first code probably won't work with either Java 8 or Java 7; it'll need to be `clear()` in both cases.  For the second one, it's not clear what `new TriggerByJobPredicate(jobKey)` was supposed to be doing, or what `values()` you were using that accepts a predicate.  The third conversion is fine.